# Bitshares - Failed to sync with the API server

Tags: api, server

I am trying to get my Full Node working with ws://127.0.0.1:8090 as API server, problem is I am getting the error message bellow on Bitshares Light:

[image]

My clock is correct and synced with internet time. I am using Windows 10 x64 and Bitshares 2 Light. I restarted my computer several times already but the error wont go away. I noticed the error only shows up when using ws://127.0.0.1:8090 as full node API server.

Also, I am getting the following error in my console log before the above "Failed to sync..." error shows up:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Win10 system does not allow bitshares WS at this moment.
Please check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket
And configure websocket for Bitshares full node on your local computer.